# Reading in encoded file in ruby results in spaces that I cant get rid of

Tags: ruby, file, encoding

Forgive me if this is rather basic, but I can't seem to get my code to work right.  All I am trying to do is open a file, read one line of it, and then parse the data.  I can parse the data fine, but when I read this file into ruby, it wants to put a space after every single character because my source file is seen as an IBM437 file or whatnot.

This is the current state of my code:

```
if(File.exists?(pingdata))
    telemetry = File.open(pingdata, 'r') { |f| f.readline }
    if String.method_defined?(:encode)
        telemetry.encode!('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '')
        telemetry.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-16')
    else
        ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE')
        telemetry = ic.iconv(telemetry)
    end
end

tArray = Array.new
tArray.clear
tArray = telemetry.split(/[\&\=]/)

puts "This is a test p0: #{tArray[0]} and p1: #{tArray[1]}"
```

the output of this looks like:

```
This is a test p0: t e s t p a r a m and p1: 0 2 8 8 8
```

I understand around encoding and stuff, but it is clear that I -dont- understand how to do it properly in ruby.  Can I get some guidance?  I've tried many, many things to try to get this to work, as you can see the (probably useless) iconv block of code above.  I'm really at my wits end trying to get this to work.

Oh, and I have tried changing f.readline to f.readline.encode but it won't work either.  I get the following error:

```
test.rb:11:in `encode': "\xFF" on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)
```

and

```
test.rb:11:in `encode': U+00A0 to ASCII-8BIT in conversion from IBM437 to UTF-8 to ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

EDIT --

I think I have figured this out.  My code, as written, actually works fine.  Just not in Ruby for Windows.  It works fine in OSX.  It works fine in *nix.  The string is stored properly in the variable.  But, it doesn't in Windows.

I had to code a stupid hack to get around it, since this is going to be a windows only utility.

Answer (score 0):

What is the file actually encoded in? Your code seems to imply that the text is actually in UTF-8 and you change it to UTF-16 and back just to replace invalid characters?

Hard for me to test exactly what you want without a sample file, but seems to me like maybe you just need to do:

```
tArray = File.read(pingdata).encode("UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :replace => '').split(/[\&\=]/)
```

Does that work?

Comment: When I do a puts telemetry.encoding after the read, it says it is IBM437.  Opening the file in a hex editor the first two bytes are FF FE.  I'm not sure what encoding that signifies.  Your solution resulted in: test.rb:14:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Comment: OK fair enough, so it's actually IBM437. That's fine.
In that case I would try:
`File.read(pingdata).encode("UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :replace => '')`
I think maybe what you were doing with the UTF-16 encoding might have been adding the space in front of each char?

Comment: Thank you for your help -- but it still puts the spaces =/.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not the best at diagnosing this sort of thing without seeing the file. Is there an example data file you can post to a fileshare somewhere that I could play with?

Comment: I'll try to get one up there, however I did find out the problem (and updated my original post).  I'll comment again when I get the file on a share.